# vanilla js - How would i display a video.currentTime value in a minutes:seconds

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my website to return its `video.currentTime` value in a **minutes**:**seconds** way

For example, this is what I need:
*00:10*

But I am getting:
*10.04*

Code:

```
video.ontimeupdate = () => { 
duration.textContent = video.currentTime
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`video.currentTime` outputs the video time in seconds.

You can just convert it to minutes and seconds.

```js
let time = video.currentTime;
let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
let seconds = Math.floor(time - minutes * 60);
let timeString = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
```

Comment: You should floor 'seconds' because that gives the most accurate video time with no errors